# Label text in python/kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am writing a code with 2 buttons to return random text to the label with kivy, but I can't get the 2 buttons to return their texts on the same line, i want the either button to overwrite whatever the second button displays on the same line

:
    BoxLayout:

```
    orientation: 'vertical'
    pos: self.pos
    Label:
        id: label1
        text: root.truths
    Label:
        id: label2
        text: root.dares

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        spaccing: 20
        padding: 25
        Button:
            text: 'Truth'
            on_press: root.truthkey()
        Button:
            text: "Dare"
            on_press: root.darekey()
```

the above is the code in the kv file and the code in the python file is show below

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import random
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


class TruthandDare(BoxLayout):
    truths = StringProperty()
    dares = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TruthandDare, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.truths=str(random.choice(['a']))
        self.dares=str(random.choice(['b']))

    def truthkey(self):
        self.truths=str(random.choice(['What is your biggest fear in a relationship',
            'What was your funniest date ever',
            'How many kids would  you  like to have',
            'What was your childhood nickname',
            'what is your favourite movie',
            'what is your favourite food',
            'what is your dream job',
            'if you were trapped on an island for 3 days, what would you take with you',
            'Do you prefer apple or android device',
            'What is your best talent',
            'Do you believe in love at first sight',
            'What is your dream wedding',
            'if you could change one thing on your body, what would it be']))

    def darekey(self):
        self.dares = str(random.choice(['b','c','d','e','f']))



class TruthDareApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TruthandDare()

if __name__=='__main__':
    TruthDareApp().run()
```

Comment: what problem you have ? do you get error message or what ?

Comment: not any error, the above program ran fine, but i want to make both button press display on a single line

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do something like:

```
Button:
    on_press: print(f'{root.truths}, {root.dares}')
```

I hope this helps, if not let me know.